# Create mask by combining the S and V channel using Bitwise operator opencv C++ opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, bitwise-operators, mask

How do I access the HSV channels in a way where I can use a bitwise operator on the S and V channel to create a new Mat that will later act as a mask?

An example code would be great.

I can't figure out if the S and V channels should be accessed in a way where they become scalars or if they should become a Mat.

If possible can someone really elaborate on that part? I am particularly lost on the aspect of getting the S and V channels in a proper format to use a bitwise operator on so that I can use the resulting value as a mask.

Comment: you can either iterate over the whole image and use bitwise operator on each pixel's elements, or you can cv::split the image to its 3 channels and use the matrix operator. It's easy to test which one will be faster in your setting and maybe depends on some parameters like image size and stuff. But in fact I don't understand how you want to combine S and V in a bitwise operation, so I'm bot sure whether your approach will make sense at all.

Comment: This is what I thought about over the weekend: I want to combine the S and V channels using a bitwise operator after performing a binary transformation. So by using inRange() or threshold() I can get the image to be represented in 0's and 1's and then I want to pull out the S and V channel and perform a bitwise operation and then apply the results back onto the image as a mask. Also, this was a recommendation by a mentor, but I am unable to predict why I would even what to do something like this.

Comment: with thresholding it makes sense. using min-thresholds for S and V makes sure your mask represents only "colorful" pixels and not gray/white/black. Just split the image, threshold 2nd and 3rd channel and use bitwise AND matrix operation.